# Trying to make a speed boost for my game but I keep getting this error :Type 'CarController' already defines a member called 'OnControllerColliderHit'

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

```
private void OnControllerColliderHit(ControllerColliderHit hit)
{
    if ((controller.collisionFlags & CollisionFlags.Sides) != 0)
    {
        if (Vector3.Dot(hit.normal, playerVelocity) < 0)
        { playerVelocity -= hit.normal * Vector3.Dot(hit.normal, playerVelocity); }
    }

    if ((controller.collisionFlags & CollisionFlags.Above) != 0)
    {
        playerVelocity.y = -1;
    }
}
//if the character controller collider is hit
void OnControllerColliderHit(ControllerColliderHit hit)
{
    switch(hit.gameObject.tag)
    {
        case"SpeedBoost":
        motorForce = 80f;
            break;
        case "Ground":
        motorForce = 50f;
        break;
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Try searching you code for the method name.  It's repeated somewhere.

Comment: @Fattie why should the error mean something different in Unity .. it is a c# compiler error saying that there are two things called `OnControllerColliderHit` in OP's class `CarController` ..

Comment: OP You have the exact same method name and signature twice in your code ...

Comment: oh i see!  right there in the code on this page the OP has two of those  :-)  @derHugo , I thought that was the error you get when you override something but mark it private accidentally.  thanks ..

Answer (score 0):

The error means exactly what it is saying: You have the exact same method name and signature twice in your code

You probably want to do

```
private void OnControllerColliderHit(ControllerColliderHit hit)
{
    if ((controller.collisionFlags & CollisionFlags.Sides) != 0)
    {
        if (Vector3.Dot(hit.normal, playerVelocity) < 0)
        { playerVelocity -= hit.normal * Vector3.Dot(hit.normal, playerVelocity); }
    }

    if ((controller.collisionFlags & CollisionFlags.Above) != 0)
    {
        playerVelocity.y = -1;
    }

    switch(hit.gameObject.tag)
    {
        case"SpeedBoost":
        motorForce = 80f;
            break;
        case "Ground":
        motorForce = 50f;
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: @Fattie you can ... we had this discussion .. it is c# after all. It doesn't matter though (if you don't mark it private it is private by c# default anyway)

Comment: you're absolutely right @derHugo you can mark those private (if you want!)  Sorry, too many languages .. whaa